# How Do I Set Database Into An Autocomplete Reference Of A Text Box In Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net

I am desiging a form with textbox.
If i type the textbox it should auto complete with value from the database.

Comment: You might want to use Combobox control for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select columnname FROM dbtable", con)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "Autofill")

    Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("columnname").ToString())
    Next
    textbox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    textbox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    textbox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

Answer (score 1):

otherwise use Ajax auto-complete Extender and use service method URL from web service page